# Content blocking iOS 9

Tags: ios9

I am working on content blocking feature introduced in iOS9.
I want to know how to get acknowledged when safari gets new url hit, and act accordingly from our app.
My requirement is to take some action from extension when new url is hit on safari.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: I made a content blocking extension for safari. I need to toggle enable  extension from settings->safari->content blockers->myApp. My question is that when user enters a url in safari, how to detect that url before loading page ?